# web.config redirect to https causing redirect loop

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config, http-status-code-301

I am trying to use this code in the web.config to redirect all pages on the website to https:// however as soon as I try this I get an infinite loop (Firefox tells me the redirect will never end properly), but I have no idea why. I only have access to the FTP and can't directly access the server so I can't use the GUI method. I'm in unfamiliar territory with this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule which, instead of checking for `HTTPs == off`, checks `HTTPS != ON`.

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I can't explain why your rule wouldn't work, but this is the rule I've been using and I've had no problem. Worth noting: I have seen occasional issues with IIS rewrite rules when using the `HTTP_HOST` value, almost as if it has the wrong value, so it may be safe to say that IIS rewrite rules are not 100% reliable.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." could it be a setting that isn't set up correctly?

Comment: @S.Wiser Do you have other rewrite rules that could be superseding this one? Is it possible the rewrite module is not installed in IIS? I think it does not come with IIS out of the box and has to be installed separately.

Comment: Yeah, there is already a rewrite rule: 
     <rule name="Redirect fleurtations.uk.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^fleurtations.uk.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.fleurtations.uk.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
(Sorry, not sure how to format this on a comment)

Comment: I wonder...could caching be the problem? Have you tried this in other browsers? Browsers tend to cache redirect http redirects very greedily and sometimes the only way to fix it is by clearing the cache.

Comment: Already tried on multiple browsers, and cleared the cache but the problem persists